# drop an element from a data frame (with error item not exist)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

I'm using `df=df.drop(index='historical book')` to delete all the rows that contain `historical book`.

the first line is the header

```
id           name book              subject                       amount
1            name1                  historical book               6
2            name2                  literature book               9
3            name3                  historical book               4
```

I get an error that it's `not found in axis`. Do you know why?

Thank you!

Comment: use: `df[df['subject'] != 'historical book']`

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
print(df[~df['subject'].str.contains('historical book')])

   id name book          subject  amount
1   2     name2  literature book       9
```